# Is there a way around the BrowserModule is already loaded error?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular8

I have a top level Angular Module that lazily loads two other modules. All modules need access to this other module that I get from node_modules. That library module imports `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` so of course I'm getting the error "Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded." Here is my code roughly:

**parent-app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../../lazyLoadedModule/src/app/app.module').then(
        mod => mod.lazyLoadedModule
      )
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**parent-app.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    **troubleModule**,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**lazy-loaded-app.module.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    **troubleModule**,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class lazyLoadedModule{}
```

I tried putting this in a sharedModule that I import in both places but that doesn't work. Is there any way around this at all? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: see the docs: https://angular.io/guide/frequent-ngmodules#browsermodule-and-commonmodule,  in Briefly replace BrowserModule by CommonModule in others modules except in main.module

Comment: I am Importing CommonModule instead of BrowserModule for my lazy loaded modules. The problem is a module that I get from a package is importing BrowserModule and BrowserAnimationsModule. I need this "package module" in all modules of my application

Comment: sorry ::glups::